# Overloading of the =operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the =operator. It should work like that:

```
MyClass a;
double b=a;
```

How can I do that?

Tschüss, Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not `operator=` (assignment). It's an initialiser. You would normally do something like this by providing a constructor that takes `MyClass` as an argument - however, you can't do that for `double`. Instead, you need to provide a conversion function for `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    operator double() const { return 5.0; }
};
```